# Python error "unexpected keyword argument 'callbacks'" when unpickling matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, pickle

I was generating plots as a result of extensive simulations. In order to change them afterwards (axis ranges etc.) I saved them not only as a pdf but also pickled the figure.

```
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = plt.figure()
# x1 and x2 are lists of floats
n1, bins1, patches = plt.hist(x1, 50, density=False, label="x1")
n2, bins2, patches = plt.hist(x2, 50, density=False, label="x2")
plt.savefig("hist.pdf")
with open("hist.pickle", "wb") as fs:
    pickle.dump(f, fs)
```

I then open them later with

```
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
I = pickle.load( open("hist.pickle", "rb" ) )
```

to change axis ranges etc. and save them again as pdfs. So far this always worked locally, but recently I run a few very long computations on a cluster with a job scheduling system. The resulting pdf files work, but when I want to open the pickled figure with the code above, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "change_axis.py", line 4, in <module>
    I = pickle.load( open( "hist.pickle", "rb" ) )
  File "/users/myname/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 161, in __setstate__
    self.__init__(**state)
```

It seems like the pickled figures are somehow broken. I already tried run the script opening the pickle file on the computer in the cluster to exclude any issues with different versions e.g. of matplotlib, but it does not help. My lessons learned is to pickle the raw data x1 and x2 next time. Is there any way, to fix it and gain access to the current figures?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it seems that the matplotlib version in the system where I was trying to load the pickled figure was older that the one used to create the pickle file. Just update matplotlib, that should do it - or at least that was sufficient for me.

```
    pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```